# PHP, HTML, Javascript execution order

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a test.php file and this file contains some PHP code, HTML elements and some internal JavaScript and some external JavaScript include.

I want to know which is first to load or execute.

PHP or HTML or JavaScript? I want to know execution order.

Your answers are greatly appreciated and very helpful to me and others also.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pragmatically speaking, this is the typical order:

- PHP runs first and constructs the page.
- The browser loads the resulting HTML (any JavaScript found gets executed immediately)
- Any JavaScript that was tied to the DOM ready or load event gets executed once the whole HTML is read and all objects are loaded respectively.

Answer (score 5):

PHP will execute first, then HTML and finally javascript.

- You send request to server, server executes your script
- Then returns rendered html to browser, browser parses HTML(inline javascript executed)
- Finally executes external included javascript files, one by one in order they are included.