# show html before php code is run

Tags: php, html

I have a raspberry pi which opens up a webpage on boot. This page loads includes a php page that listens on udp port for input.
When the input is received I want another page to load, but I'm having trouble doing this.

Here's index.html

```
<html style="background-color:#0085b3;">
<body>
  <img src="bg.jpg"/>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>

<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#content").load("udp.php");
});
</script>
</html>
```

and udp.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($socket, '10.10.10.25', 5000);

$from = '';
$port = 0;
socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 12, 0, $from, $port);

$buf = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $buf);

$conn = null;

socket_close($socket);

die("<script>location.href = 'http://10.10.10.20/main.php'</script>");
?>
```

What happens is that the die function is echoed on the raspberry and the browser doesn't load the main.php webpage

I tried using a single php page to display the image and then listen to the input, but the php code is run at once and displays the html only after receiving some input.

index.php

```
<?php

echo '<html style="background-color:#0085b3;">';
echo '<body>';
echo '<img src="bg.jpg"/>';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';

session_start();

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($socket, '10.10.10.25', 5000);

$from = '';
$port = 0;
socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 12, 0, $from, $port);

$buf = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $buf);

$conn = null;

socket_close($socket);

die("<script>location.href = 'http://localhost/plc/main.php'</script>");
?>
```

Comment: Why are you redirecting like that? why not use `header(location: <URL>); die();`?

Comment: use sleep() method i think i will work

Comment: PHP code runs always first and has to complete, there's no way around it -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877399/php-html-javascript-execution-order

Answer (score 3):

PHP will execute first, then HTML and finally javascript.

- You send request to server, server executes your script.
- Then returns rendered html to browser, browser parses HTML (inline javascript 
  executed).
- Finally executes external included javascript files, one by one in order they are included.